# The button called "Button" is crashing. Can anyone provide assistance?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

This is the xml and the java code
The button keeps crashing and the purpose of this is to take in text from the editText feature

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonSaveEvent"
            android:text="Save Event"
            android:layout_below="@id/cal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText"/>

public void buttonSaveEvent(View view, EditText editText)
        {
            eventsavebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(!(editText.equals(""))){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Event Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter an event...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use edittext.getText().toString().equals(your string)